# Why does scalac take the Java vararg method instead of the single argument

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, variadic-functions

We're using [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) as database and based upon a definition I'm creating a [type mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).
This mapping is basically a JSON object which gets built with the `XContentBuilder` of elasticsearch Java-API.

In my scala file I've defined an Enumeration object that holds the possible elasticsearch data-types like this:

```
object TypeMapping extends Enumeration {

    val StringType = DataType("string")
    val FloatType = DataType("float")
    ...
    val GeoShapeType = DataType("geo_shape")
    val AttachmentType = DataType("attachment")

    final case class DataType(esType: String) extends Val {
        override def toString: String = esType
    }
}
```

Now when I use this in the creation of the mapping JSON like this:

```
val builder = jsonBuilder.startObject("name").field("type", StringType).endObject
```

the scala compiler can nicely resolves all the methods to call; no errors or warnings.

The method `field` is overloaded, each receiving a `String` parameter `name` and a parameter `value`. These values can be specific (`String`, `int`, `int[]`, etc.) or vararg (`String...`, `int...`, etc.) but there's also an `Object` variant for both specific and vararg calls.

Now I would expect that the scala compiler would choose the `field(String name, Object value)` in the case I'm describing here, but to my suprise I find that the `field(String name, Object... value)` is being called.

I do not understand why this is happening. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: How do you know its choosing the varargs method. What is happening to show that?

Comment: The resulting JSON object is different. The vararg call creates an Array field value, while the non-vararg creates a String field value. I just posted my partial code explaining what API calls I make. You could also reproduce this by creating a Java class file with the two methods printing which is called and invoking it in a Scala class.

Comment: Yeah the latter would be a better question I think as this isn't really anything to do with Elasticsearch per se. As a side note, I created https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s to get around the mismatch between the Java client and Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Scala picks the varargs version as more specific because `(String, Array[Any])` can be applied to the other signature `field(name: String, value: Any)`. (And not vice-versa.)

Given that both methods are in the same class, I'm not sure if there is a canonical workaround besides reflective access:

```
  type Picker = {
    def f(name: String, value: Any): Int
  }
  Console println x.f("hi", "high")                // varargs
  Console println (x: Picker).f("hi", "high")      // not
```

Disambiguating:

```
public class JOver {
    public int f(String name, Object value) { return 1; }
    public int f(String name, Object... values) { return 2; }
}
```

Comment: I'm calling Java API from scala here. The `StringType` would be seen as of type `Any` I guessed, which I expected to map on the `java.lang.Object` type, but if I understand you correctly it is seen as `Array[Any]` and therfore maps on `java.lang.Object...`?

Comment: I'm not a user, but checked this sig in XContentBuilder.  Overload resolution in Scala just looks at the sigs of the methods that apply to your args.  An Array is an Object but not vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse an Array is an Object and not vice-versa. If Scala looks at the signature of the methods that apply to the arguments, then why does it pick Object... (or Array[Any]) instead of Object? Are you saying that because both signatures apply, the vararg is more specific and therefore picked?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Tangentially, https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4728  https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8344

Comment: Ok. But is that only the case for Object? When I change `StringType` into `StringType.toString` the method with sig `(String, String)` is picked and not `(String, String...)`. Also here both signatures apply, but now the vararg is not more specific?